# XAML ImageBrush using a BitmapImage without a URI

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

I have the following XAML that displays a cover image for a book using a URI:

```
<Rectangle.Fill>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding CoverUrl}" />
</Rectangle.Fill>
```

However, the image I would like to use is not on disk anywhere or accessible via a URI; it comes from inside a binary file that I parse out into a `BitmapImage` object.

When I create a `BitmapImage` object via code, the resulting object's `BaseUri` and `UriSource` properties are null.  How can I get the `ImageBrush` to use a `BitmapImage` that resides in memory instead of reading it in from a URI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ImageSource property is of type ImageSource, not Uri or string... actually, a conversion happens when you assign a Uri to it. You can bind the ImageBrush directly to a property that returns an ImageSource

```
<Rectangle.Fill>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Cover}" />
</Rectangle.Fill>


private ImageSource _cover;
public ImageSource Cover
{
    get
    {
        if (_cover == null)
        {
            _cover = LoadImage();
        }
        return _cover;
    }
}
```